# Rephrasing nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools

The following code has multiple loops and I want to reduce it to optimise the time complexity as well.

```
for a in file1:
    if a[0] in [i[1] for i in file2]:
        for b in file2:
            if a[0] == b[1]:
                c.append(int(b[0]))
            continue
    else:
        # do stuff
```

I tried the following to make it more efficient. Although, I couldn't find an alternative to the `if` statement.

```
for a, b in zip(file1, file2):
    if a[0] in [i[1] for i in file2]:
        if a[0] == b[1]:
            c.append(int(b[0]))
        continue
    else:
        # do stuff
```

Also, the outputs for both the operations are different. The first piece of code does show a correct result.

Comment: The first code sample iterates over `file2` twice, which seems wasteful.  You might as well  remove the first `if` statement.

Comment: Just note that 'zip' gives us pairs. Let a=[1,2,3], b = ['a', 'b', 'c'], then list(zip(a,b)) = [(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c')].

If you need to rewrite your code using less loops (but why?..), try itertools.product instead of zip. Then note that your first 'if' if useless and just increases time of evaluation: you loop over file2 two times, first to determine if any element fits and then to find it. Then 'continue' in first snippet does nothing, it's at the end of loop. And this code will always be O(n^2) or more, because you need to iterate over each pair of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution is actually slower. The idea of zip (or rather, it should be like itertools.product, zip produces `N` pairs) produces `NxM` pairs, so your entire solution is now `O(NxMxM)`, whereas the first should be `O(Nx2M)`. I'm not sure what your `continue` statement does, that seems pointless.

My tip is to precalculate some of your values, and to use sets/dictionaries. `[i[1] for i in file2]` will be the same every loop, so take that out.

Also, since you are aligning `b` with `a` by value, let's instead create a reverse lookup dictionary.

```
# build reverse lookup dictionary
reverse = dict()
for b in file2:
    if not b[1] in reverse:
        reverse[b[1]] = [b]
    else:
        reverse[b[1]].append(b)

# check to see if a[0] matches any b[1], if it does append all matching b[0] to c
for a in file1:
    if a[0] in reverse:
        b_valid = reverse[a[0]]
        for b in b_valid:
            c.append(int(b[0]))
    else:
        # do stuff
```

This brings it down somewhere along the lines of `O(N+M)` (potentially worse given poor dictionary creation times and lookup times).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
next((x for x in file2 if a[0] == x[1]), None)
```

That will give you what fits, and you should be able to append if it is not `None`.